# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller - 302 error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to test mTLS but I am getting 302 when I curl the host defined in ingress resource.

```
$ curl https://my.example.com --cert client.crt --key client.key -k
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "default/ca-secret"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: my.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-svc
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Here's the ingress controller log:

```
kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-79236f5c-gzgwl -n ingress-nginx -f
...
...
192.168.219.64 - - [15/Aug/2022:17:56:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 138 "-" "curl/7.29.0" 80 0.000 [] [] - - - - ae4b4fd210
```

I can curl the service nginx-svc successfully using the cluster-ip associated with the service. Any idea what's wrong with the ingress configuration?

Comment: is the upstream using the certs? from `302` sound like upstream does not understand the certs. you should turn it off `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "false"`

Comment: Try `curl https://my.example.com --cert client.crt --key client.key -k -v -o /dev/null` to see the headers -- you can then see what it is redirecting to. A possibility is that it's redirecting `https://my.example.com` to `https://my.example.com/`

Comment: @BlenderFox: Thank you! Verbose suggestion really helped! Got `warning: certificate file name "client.crt" handled as nickname; please use "./client.crt" to force file name`. Can you kindly post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`curl https://my.example.com --cert client.crt --key client.key -k -v -o /dev/null`

to see the headers -- you can then see what it is redirecting to. A possibility is that it's redirecting `https://my.example.com` to `https://my.example.com/`